# How to display load more functionality using select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

I have a load more functionality code that works perfectly fine for list items
[Fiddle for list items](https://jsfiddle.net/learner001/4qqgma5L/3/)

Now I am trying to replicate this same functionality inside a select tag. When a user clicks on option tag 3 values along with load more inside the dropdown should be visible and after clicking on load more next set of 3 items should be visible without closing the dropdown

Code that i am trying is

```
<select class="form-control" id="myList">
  <option  id="sec" value="">Please select</option>  
  <option  id="sec" value="1">1</option>
  <option  id="sec" value="2">2</option>
  <option  id="sec" value="3">3</option>
  <option  id="sec" value="4">4</option>
  <option  id="sec" value="5">5</option>
  <option  id="sec" value="6">6</option>
  <option  id="sec" value="7">7</option>
  <option  id="sec" value="8">8</option>
  <option  id="sec" value="9">9</option>
  <option value="">
    <div id="loadMore">Load more</div>
  </option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function () {
    size_li = $("#sec").size();
    x=3;
    $('#sec:lt('+x+')').show();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        x= (x+5 <= size_li) ? x+5 : size_li;
        $(' #sec:lt('+x+')').show();
        if(x == size_li){
            $('#loadMore').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Complete code for select tag [is here](https://jsfiddle.net/learner001/pegctker/14/)

Can anyone please tell how I can achieve this feature

Comment: So let say if clicked on learn more inside the select box what will be selected value for the select box?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the IDs must be unique. Change them to classes or use different IDs.

Secondly, an [option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) can contain (hence avoid the div container):

> Permitted content: Text, possibly with escaped characters (like é).

For the last, set a value to the first option in order to simplify its selection.

The click event handler cannot be attached to the option but to the select.

Try to avoid global variables: they create confusion and in a long term you will troubles testing and fixing your code.

```js
$('#myList .sec:lt(3)').toggleClass('sec');
$('#myList').on('click', function (e) {
    if (this.selectedOptions[0].classList.contains('loadMore')) {
        $('#myList').val('0');
        $('#myList .sec:lt(5)').toggleClass('sec');
        if ($('#myList .sec').length == 0) {
            $('#myList .loadMore').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.sec{
  display:none;
}
.loadMore {
    color:green;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<select class="form-control" id="myList">
    <option  class="sec" value="0">Please select</option>
    <option  class="sec" value="1">1</option>
    <option  class="sec" value="2">2</option>
    <option  class="sec" value="3">3</option>
    <option  class="sec" value="4">4</option>
    <option  class="sec" value="5">5</option>
    <option  class="sec" value="6">6</option>
    <option  class="sec" value="7">7</option>
    <option  class="sec" value="8">8</option>
    <option  class="sec" value="9">9</option>
    <option  class="sec" value="10">10</option>
    <option  class="sec" value="11">11</option>
    <option  class="sec" value="12">12</option>
    <option  class="sec" value="13">13</option>
    <option  class="sec" value="14">14</option>
    <option  class="sec" value="15">15</option>
    <option class="loadMore" value="">Load more</option>
</select>
```

Comment: it  works fine but, whenever load more is getting clicked the dropdown is getting closed, can you please look into it

Comment: with a select you cannot. Instead you may use a bootstrap plugin like [bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)

Answer (score 0):

I have made few changes which I will be listed below :

Changes in **option** `id='sec'` to `class='sec'`. The difference between an ID and a class is that an ID can be used to identify one element, whereas a class can be used to identify more than one so we cannot use same **ID** more than once in a html page.

Instead of a click event for `option tag` which doesn't work, I have changed click event to `select`

`var x` will be keeping the **current state** of the `select box` if clicked `loadMore` option `x` will be updated.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var size_li = $(".sec").size();
  var x=0;
  $('#myList').on('click', function () {
      if($(this).val() == "load"){
        x += 3; // for showing next 3 option
        $('.sec:lt('+x+')').show(); // will show till x value from total option with sec class
        if(x >= size_li){
          $('#loadMore').hide();
        }
      }
  });
});
```

```css
.sec{ display:none;
}
#loadMore {
    color:green;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#loadMore:hover {
    color:black;
}
#showLess {
    color:red;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:none;
}
#showLess:hover {
    color:black;
}
#myList li{ display:none;
}
#loadMore {
    color:green;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#loadMore:hover {
    color:black;
}
#showLess {
    color:red;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:none;
}
#showLess:hover {
    color:black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="myList">
  <option value="">Please select</option>  
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option  value="3">3</option>
  <option  class="sec" value="4">4</option>
  <option  class="sec" value="5">5</option>
  <option  class="sec" value="6">6</option>
  <option  class="sec" value="7">7</option>
  <option  class="sec" value="8">8</option>
  <option  class="sec" value="9">9</option>
  <option id="loadMore" value="load">
    Load more
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: it seems to work fine but, whenever load more is getting clicked the dropdown is getting closed, can you please look into it

Comment: that's the default behaviour of a select box if that's not your expected behaviour I wonder why you choose select box?

Comment: it is a part of a form where i need to send data to the backend so I thought it might work, if there is any other possibility please let me know

Comment: then i will suggest to use [bootstrap button group dropdown](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/button-group/#nesting) instead of select. add a hidden field to your form and update value whenever we click on btngroup list. the benefit of using btngroup you can play around however you want.